# For which orders does there exist a Latin square which remains a Latin square after replacing each row by its square (interpreted as permutations)?

Tags: combinatorics, latin-square

*Question*: For which orders $n$ does there exist a Latin square of order $n$ which remains a Latin square after replacing each row by its square (when the rows are interpreted as permutations)?

If $L=(l_{ij})$ then row $i$ corresponds to the permutation $j \mapsto l_{ij}$.

For example, the rows of this (randomly generated) Latin square
$$\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 3 & 4 & 2 \\
4 & 2 & 1 & 3 \\
3 & 1 & 2 & 4 \\
2 & 4 & 3 & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix}
\leftrightarrow
\begin{bmatrix}
(234) \\
(143) \\
(132) \\
(124) \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
and if we square the permuations on the right, we get
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
(234)^2 \\
(143)^2 \\
(132)^2 \\
(124)^2 \\
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
(243) \\
(134) \\
(123) \\
(142) \\
\end{bmatrix}
\leftrightarrow
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 4 & 2 & 3 \\
3 & 2 & 4 & 1 \\
2 & 3 & 1 & 4 \\
4 & 1 & 3 & 2 \\
\end{bmatrix}.$$

A randomly generated order-$5$ example is:
$$\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 4 & 2 & 5 & 3 \\
4 & 5 & 3 & 2 & 1 \\
3 & 1 & 5 & 4 & 2 \\
2 & 3 & 4 & 1 & 5 \\
5 & 2 & 1 & 3 & 4 \\
\end{bmatrix}
\leftrightarrow
\begin{bmatrix}
(2453) \\
(1425) \\
(1352) \\
(1234) \\
(1543) \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
After squaring the rows, we get
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
(2453)^2 \\
(1425)^2 \\
(1352)^2 \\
(1234)^2 \\
(1543)^2 \\
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
(25)(34) \\
(12)(45) \\
(15)(23) \\
(13)(24) \\
(14)(35) \\
\end{bmatrix}
\leftrightarrow
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 5 & 4 & 3 & 2 \\
2 & 1 & 3 & 5 & 4 \\
5 & 3 & 2 & 4 & 1 \\
3 & 4 & 1 & 2 & 5 \\
4 & 2 & 5 & 1 & 3 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

After generating $60000$ random Latin squares of order $6$, my computer didn't find an example.

This question is something I happen to be thinking about.  I haven't put too much thought into solving this; it's just a curious distraction vaguely related to a research problem.

Comment: If $n$ is a prime, then won't using the identity permutation at the top row and powers of a fixed $p$-cycle elsewhere work? If it does, I'm sure you knew about it. Just felt like bringing it up anyway :-) (and checking whether I understood the question).

Comment: Hmm... indeed.  I think that strategy works for all odd $n$.  (It's very possible this is an easy question.  It seemed interesting to think about, but since it's only tangentially related to what I'm working on, I thought I'd think about it more socially.)